# Lazy Pirate pattern with real request data

Tags: python, zeromq

I am learning zmq with PyZMQ binding and i have trouble with Lazy Pirate pattern.
So, here is a code for [Lazy Pirate server](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3alpserver) and [Lazy Pirate client](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3alpclient).

In example client sends request, but it is simple number. How can i make a real request with text data and keep pattern realization?

Also, i don't trully understand `sequence` variable in client code - it is incrementing infinitely => won't python crash when `sequence` reaches int variable maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, the `sequence` variable in the code is basically a message identifier. There are two ways in which a single request attempt can fail:

1. The request message can simply never send
2. The request message sends, but the client gets tired of waiting and times out before the response gets back to it

In the second case, if you don't have the `sequence` number, you don't know which of your requests is actually the one that succeeded.

Consider this client history:

- Send request #1
- Timeout
- Send request #2
- Timeout
- Send request #3
- Receive response

Which request trigged the response? It could be any of the three requests, because of the second kind of request failure mentioned above. With the `sequence` number in the response, we can know exactly which request is the one the server processed.

The idea behind the "Malformed reply from server" in the sample client is that, if the client is on request #3 (having timed out on requests #1 and #2), it throws away responses #n (where n < 3) until it gets to response #3, which it accepts.

To send more than the sequence number, use a serialization format and send a whole object.

For example, I could define `class MyRequest { int sequence; string text; }` and then send that as JSON to the server.

The infinitely incrementing `sequence` variable could be replaced with an int64 and then it would be fine, or you could do something like use a GUID as the request identified instead.

Comment: The above answer is wrong in most respects. First, as Hintjens clearly states on page 147 in the O'Riely book ZeroMQ ... "The client sequences each message and checks that replies come back exactly in order:that no requests or replies are lost, and no replies come back more than once or out of order." ... "You don't need sequence numbers in a production application; they just help us trust our design." So, from the horse's mouth, the Sequence # is just to convince you the thing works, it plays no role in insuring proper returns from the server.

Comment: Additionally, the idea behind "Malformed reply from server" has nothing to do with counting returns and insuring their proper order. That is done automatically by ZeroMQ. That error message is in the }else{ clause testing for a NULL string returned from char *reply = zstr_recv(client). IE: It's just a "WTF" message indicating that for some unexplained reason zstr_recv() returned a NULL string.

Comment: @user2548100 With the REQ-REP pairing, ZeroMQ will ensure no messages are dropped or out of order, even if the HWM is reached, correct. If you switch to something like ROUTER-ROUTER, this is no longer the case, because messages can be dropped at the HWM. The "pattern" being shown in the example being referenced by the OP generalizes to the asynchronous socket types, which is why I answered as I did. Of course, if you stick to REQ-REP, everything is really simple and you don't need this.

Comment: @user2548100 I've used ZMQ extensively. To say the answer is "wrong in most respects" is a bit extreme.

Comment: The OP's question wasn't about naked sockets. The whole point of using a messaging system is guaranteed delivery. You answered some question, just not any the OP asked. I'm sorry you can't swallow your pride and cop to a "My Bad", because somebody is going to be mislead by your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Timothy Shields' answer above is 100% incorrect. You can read Hintjen's comments in this [free for download version of his book](http://hintjens.com/books) **Code Connected Volume 1**. The important bit is from page 141 as follows ...

> The client sequences each message and checks that replies come back
>   exactly in order: that no requests or replies are lost, and no replies
>   come back more than once, or out of order. Run the test a few times
>   until you’re convinced that this mechanism actually works. You don’t
>   need sequence numbers in a production application; they just help us
>   trust our design.

For an interesting discussion of ways naked TCP can fail, this is [a good discussion](http://www.cliffc.org/blog/2013/08/15/tcp-is-unreliable/#comments). Read the comments. I've no doubt that Tim is very knowledgable, he just slipped up in failing to recognize that the Lazy Pirate Pattern in particular **ONLY** uses REQ-REP, and so is more reliable than his comments imply.